# How to reference a field by reflection

Tags: .net, reflection, c#-2.0, fieldinfo

Sorry for the title, it's not explicit.

[Further to my precedent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315905/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-method-by-reflection), I want to subscribe a method to an event object retrieved dynamically (via reflection). The object in question is a field of a Control :

```
public void SubscribeEvents(Control control)
{
    Type controlType = control.GetType();
    FieldInfo[] fields = controlType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    MethodInfo method = typeof(Trace).GetMethod("WriteTrace");

    // "button1" hardcoded for the sample
    FieldInfo f = controlType.GetField("button1", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // "Click" hardcoded for the sample
    EventInfo eInfo = f.FieldType.GetEvent("Click");

    if (eInfo != null)
    {
        EventHandler dummyDelegate = (s, e) => WriteTrace(s, e, eInfo.Name);
        Delegate realDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eInfo.EventHandlerType, dummyDelegate.Target, dummyDelegate.Method);
        eInfo.AddEventHandler(?????, realDelegate); // How can I reference the variable button1 ???
    }
}
```

I don't know how to reference the variable 'button1'. I've tried something like this :

```
public void SubscribeEvents(Control control)
{
    Type controlType = control.GetType();
    FieldInfo[] fields = controlType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    MethodInfo method = typeof(Trace).GetMethod("WriteTrace");

    // "button1" hardcoded for the sample
    FieldInfo f = controlType.GetField("button1", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // "Click" hardcoded for the sample
    EventInfo eInfo = f.FieldType.GetEvent("Click");

    Type t = f.FieldType;
    object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

    f.GetValue(o);

    if (eInfo != null)
    {
        EventHandler dummyDelegate = (s, e) => WriteTrace(s, e, eInfo.Name);
        Delegate realDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eInfo.EventHandlerType, dummyDelegate.Target, dummyDelegate.Method);
        eInfo.AddEventHandler(o, realDelegate); // Why can I refer to the variable button1 ???
    }
}
```

But I have an exception here :

```
        f.GetValue(o);
```

System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=Field 'button1' defined on type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' is not a field on the target object which is of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you're trying to create a new instance of `Button` and trying to get the value of its `button1` property, which obviously does not exist.

Replace this:

```
Type t = f.FieldType;
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

f.GetValue(o);
```

with this:

```
object o = f.GetValue(control);
```

You can use a method like this to obtain the value of a field for any object:

```
public static T GetFieldValue<T>(object obj, string fieldName)
{
    if (obj == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

    var field = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Public |
                                                  BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                  BindingFlags.Instance);

    if (field == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("fieldName", "No such field was found.");

    if (!typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Field type and requested type are not compatible.");

    return (T)field.GetValue(obj);
}
```

Comment: I have a problem : it works fine with button1 (and other buttons) but when it's a custom field it returns null : 
object o = f.GetValue(control); // if f is a fieldinfo from a field of type MyClass, o = null

Whereas f has good values

Comment: @Florian: What the heck is a "custom field?"

Comment: @cdhowie :
private MyClass _myClass; // The "custom" field (bad translation ?        
private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;

Comment: Then you will need to use a `FieldInfo` object that you obtained from the type `typeof(MyClass)`.  `FieldInfo` objects from one type cannot be used on unrelated types, even if they share field names.  See the method that I posted -- you can use that to obtain arbitrary fields on any object.  For example: `Button button = GetFieldValue<Button>("button1", _myClass);`

Comment: I have the same problem. For a button control, it's ok, but for a  control of type MyClass, the line "return (T)field.GetValue(obj);" returns null

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is somewhere else. Thanks you for your help !

Comment: @Florian: No problem! Note that if that line is returning null, it means the value stored in the field is null.  If the `obj` parameter is invalid or if the `field` object doesn't reference any field on the `obj` parameter, or something else is wrong, `GetValue()` will throw an exception, not return null.