# C# How would I get a field through reflection once and make a delegate that returns its value for future use?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection, delegates, attributes

**My use case**: In my game I have an overlay that tracks any field with the '[TrackedField]' attribute. I want it to display the name of the variable, and the current value. Reflection being a bit of an expensive operation, I was looking for a way to retrieve the value once through reflection, and then make a delegate function, which doesn't use reflection, that returns the field's value. That way it can be called whenever I want to update that value on the overlay.

I actually don't know if what I'm asking is even possible, or if there would be a better way to retrieve this value. I've searched around for the past couple days, but all I was able to dig up was [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336042/how-to-reference-a-field-by-reflection). It will most likely be updated multiple times a second, so I'd like to avoid repeated use of reflection if I can.

Currently my code just gets every variable name (or a label defined in the attribute) and displays it with a dummy delegate that just reads "error":

```
MonoBehaviour[] sceneActive = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>();

foreach (MonoBehaviour mono in sceneActive)
{
    System.Type monoType = mono.GetType();

    // Retreive the fields from the mono instance
    FieldInfo[] objectFields = monoType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    // search all fields and find the attribute [TrackedField]
    for (int i = 0; i < objectFields.Length; i++)
    {
        TrackedFieldAttribute attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(objectFields[i], typeof(TrackedFieldAttribute)) as TrackedFieldAttribute;

        // if we detect any attribute add it to the overlay
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            trackerBar.AddTab(attribute.label == null ? objectFields[i].Name : attribute.label, () => { return "error"; },attribute.color);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the '[TrackedField]' attribute in action:

```
[TrackedField]
private bool consoleOpen = false;
[TrackedField("MyLabel")]
private bool overlayShown = false;
[TrackedField("ColoredLabel", 50, 50, 255)]
```

It results in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk0Uw.png) on the overlay, if you were curious.

And if you were interested in what the attribute looked like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class TrackedFieldAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string _label;
    private Color _color;

    public TrackedFieldAttribute()
    {
        _label = null;
        _color = default(Color);
    }

    public TrackedFieldAttribute(string label)
    {
        _label = label;
        _color = default(Color);
    }

    public TrackedFieldAttribute(float red = 0, float green = 0, float blue = 0)
    {
        _label = null;
        _color = new Color(red / 255f, green / 255f, blue / 255f);
    }

    public TrackedFieldAttribute(string label, float red = 0, float green = 0, float blue = 0)
    {
        _label = label;
        _color = new Color(red / 255f, green / 255f, blue / 255f);
    }

    public string label
    {
        get { return _label; }
        set { _label = value; }
    }

    public Color color
    {
        get { return _color; }
        set { _color = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid using reflection in Unity. Why do you need this? Maybe there is a workaround without reflection....

Comment: It's for a general purpose debugging tool. If there is a workaround that can still use the '[TrackedField]' attribute I'd be all for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Unity but in in classic .NET Framework this is possible:

```
public class FieldAccessor
{
    private delegate object FieldGetter(object instance);       
    private FieldGetter getter;

    public FieldAccessor(FieldInfo field)
    {
        ParameterExpression instanceParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "instance");

        MemberExpression member = Expression.Field(
            field.IsStatic ? null : Expression.Convert(instanceParameter, field.DeclaringType), // (TInstance)instance
            field);

        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda<FieldGetter>(
            Expression.Convert(member, typeof(object)), // object return type
            instanceParameter); // instance (object)

        getter = (FieldGetter)lambda.Compile();
    }

    public object Get(object instance)
    {
        return getter(instance);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
FieldInfo fi = typeof(MyType).GetField(...);

// creating the accessor is slow so cache this accessor instance:
var accessor = new FieldAccessor(fi);

// and then just use it like this:
var value = accessor.Get(myInstance);
```

Comment: I can't seem to call 'DeclaringType', or I'm not looking in the correct namespace. It may not exist in the version of Mono Unity uses.

Comment: Ah, never mind, it was the DeclaringType of the field parameter. I was trying to use it generically.

Comment: You are right, fixed. It was a property in my version.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Unity as well. You may try to replace your delegate `() => { return "error"; }` with

```
() => { return objectFields[i].GetValue(mono); }
```

Note that this delegate will return an object and just in case you should handle `null` values.

Also, it is still an expensive call but at least you cut on finding fields and enumerating attributes that are high expensive operations.

Comment: This also works, and looks very clean! How does it compare to [taffer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46878336/2936627) solution in terms of performance?

Comment: This solution uses reflection on every call while the other solution will be as fast as a normal field access (after instantiation).